# SQL Server: Granting db_datawriter on all databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to manage permissions and access to a SQL Server database server on a development machine. I've created a local windows group (called DBReaderGroup) and assigned various people to it. The group was created as a SQL Server login successfully:

`create login [MYMACHINE\DBReaderGroup] from windows`

My goal is to grant this group read/write access to all databases (which are constantly being added and dropped). Is it possible to configure the right settings so that SQL Server manages this?

My biggest challenge is that each time a db is created, I have to update the "User Mapping" settings for this group on the new database.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the login to the Model database in the db_datawriter role, and any new database will give that login full write access by default. This won't work, however, if the databases being added are from other sources (ie restored versions).